# Группировка истории по последнему пользователю

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица с записями в истории по тикетам.

Надо cделать выборку, сгруппировав пользователей. Для каждого пользователя взять только одну строку (такую, что дата максимальна).

Как это сделать? Я пробовал вот так:

```
CREATE TABLE [TICKETHISTORY](
    [ID] varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    [TICKETID] varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    [FIELDNAME] [varchar](64) NULL,
    [NOTE] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CREATEUSER] varchar(10) NULL,
    [CREATEDATE] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TICKETHISTORY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [TICKETHISTORY] ([ID],[TICKETID],[FIELDNAME],[NOTE],[CREATEUSER],[CREATEDATE])
     VALUES('1','100','DEPART1','Notes1','User1', '2017-01-01')

INSERT INTO [TICKETHISTORY] ([ID],[TICKETID],[FIELDNAME],[NOTE],[CREATEUSER],[CREATEDATE])
     VALUES('2','100','DEPART1','Notes2','User1','2017-01-02')

INSERT INTO [TICKETHISTORY] ([ID],[TICKETID],[FIELDNAME],[NOTE],[CREATEUSER],[CREATEDATE])
     VALUES('3','100','DEPART2','Notes3','User1','2017-01-03')

INSERT INTO [TICKETHISTORY] ([ID],[TICKETID],[FIELDNAME],[NOTE],[CREATEUSER],[CREATEDATE])
     VALUES('4','101','DEPART1','Notes4','User2','2017-01-01')

INSERT INTO [TICKETHISTORY] ([ID],[TICKETID],[FIELDNAME],[NOTE],[CREATEUSER],[CREATEDATE])
     VALUES('5','101','DEPART2','Notes5','User2','2017-01-02')
```

В выборке должны остаться только строки 3 и 5:

```
3 100 User1 2017-01-03

5 101 User2 2017-01-02
```

Сам запрос:

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[TICKETID]
      ,[CREATEUSER]
      ,MAX([CREATEDATE])
FROM [TICKETHISTORY]
GROUP BY TICKETID
```

И еще пробовал все поля перечислить. БОЛ читал https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177673(v=sql.105) но чтото не нашел подходящего.

Comment: если у вас 3 юзера, почему оставить 2 строки только?

Comment: ой правда! старый пример скопировал

Comment: А почему вы having не хотите использовать? В котором можно указать select date=max(date)

Comment: @Kawalski А как это сделать? Можете привести пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно оставить запись только по последней дате по каждому юзеру, то вы можете использовать соединение с таблицей, где для каждого юзера будет считаться дата последней записи, и по условиям отсекать.

Логика примерно такая:

```
SELECT ID
      ,TICKETID
      ,CREATEUSER
      ,M.MAXDATE
FROM TICKETHISTORY TH
    JOIN (SELECT CREATEUSER, MAX(CREATEDATE) as MAXDATE
          FROM TICKETHISTORY
          GROUP BY CREATEUSER
         ) M 
      ON TH.CREATEUSER = M.CREATEUSER AND TH.CREATEDATE = M.MAXDATE
```

Comment: ваш запрос не до конца отвечает требованиям Автора: ему требуется одна строка для каждого пользователя, в вашем запросе допускается несколько строк с одинаковой датой создания

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
WITH CTE AS
 (SELECT [ID]
    ,[TICKETID]
    ,[CREATEUSER]
    ,[CREATEDATE]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [CREATEUSER] ORDER BY [CREATEDATE] DESC) 
as rw
FROM  [TICKETHISTORY]
 )
SELECT   [ID]
    ,[TICKETID]
    ,[CREATEUSER]
    ,[CREATEDATE]
FROM     CTE
WHERE    rw <= 1
```

Или так

```
SELECT   [ID],
         [TICKETID],
         [CREATEUSER],
         MAX([CREATEDATE])
FROM     [TICKETHISTORY]
Group by [ID],
         [TICKETID],
         [CREATEUSER]
```